# Error initializing Metron Grok Parser

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, apache-storm, hortonworks-data-platform

We created HDP and Metron clusters using Ambari. We used Kafka to ingrest data. We have kafka producer kafka topics and kafka consumer. It seems all kafka jobs work fine but in storm we got errors like:

```
Error: Grok parser unable to initialize grok parser: Unable to load /patterns/nova from either classpath or HDFS at org.apache.metron.parsers.GrokParser.init
```

Does anyone know why we got this error?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Presuming your pattern is in HDFS, you have to use /apps/metron/patterns/nova for your grokpath in the parser. I faced the same issue. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because you have created a new grok parser, but have not uploaded the pattern, with its supporting patterns to the specified HDFS location. Try creating the /patterns folder in hdfs, and upload your grok patterns in a file named nova. You should then restart your parser topology, and it should find the patterns. Note that the path must match that given in the parser config for your grok parser config in zookeeper.